# Code sample for freeing advantage database server table

Tags: delphi, advantage-database-server

I have a set of tables that were included in an Advantage Database data dictionary.  The dictionary is no longer available, and the tables will not open.

I would like to free those tables using code (not the Advantage Data Architect).

The only reference I can find to this is a function listed in the help called ADSDDFreeTable.

The documentation for the function is at this link:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?ace_adsddfreetable.htm

but it does not offer a code sample, and I cannot understand how to use it.

Would anyone be kind enough to show a code sample of how this function is used (with variables, not literals, for file names, etc)

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ace.pas` defines `AdsDDFreeTable` as

```
function AdsDDFreeTable( pucTableName: PAceChar;
                         pucPassword: PAceChar ):UNSIGNED32; {$IFDEF WIN32}stdcall;{$ENDIF}{$IFDEF LINUX}cdecl;{$ENDIF}
```

The same `Ace.pas` defines `PAceChar`:

```
type
  PAceChar = PAnsiChar;
```

Therefore, the call to the function should be fairly straightforward:

```
var
  TableName: AnsiString;
begin
  TableName := 'C:\Data\MyTable.adt`;
  if AdsDDFreeTable(PAnsiChar(TableName), nil) <> ADS_FREETABLEFAILED then
    ShowMessage('Table removed from datadictionary')
  else
    // Call ADSGetLastError to retrieve reason for failure;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Ken's solution (+1), there is also a standalone command line utility named freeadt.exe that will free ADT tables from their associated data dictionary.  I believe it is installed with [Advantage Data Architect](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=19&Product=8&Platform=6).

If you run it from the command line with no parameters, it displays usage information.  In general, though, you can give it a folder name (to process all the tables) or a specific file as a parameter.